# Can I develop apple watch app that uses heartbeat, accelerometer etc without owing apple watch? only using simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, watchos

I want to build an watchOS app which uses heartbeat data and I don't have apple watch yet.
Is it possible using simulator(watchOS simulator)?

Comment: Yes to some extent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use `HKWorkoutSession` also there is a nice [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2168-preparing-for-the-apple-watch-a-prototype-heartbeat-app) creating a prototype would be useful for you.